# 2-3 search tree implementation in c++

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm looking for a c++ implementation of 2-3 search tree

Have anybody come across something of this sort anywhere on the net?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you need it for where the standard `set` and `map` containers don't surfice (which are based on red-black trees, so equivalent to a 2-4 tree)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cs.ucr.edu/cs14/cs14_06win/slides/2-3_trees_covered.pdf 
 While it does not give an implementaion, it gives enough background to implement 2-3 trees (including node structure, insertions, deletions, traversals, search etc. ).

Answer (score 0):

this one might be helpful for future.

http://cplusplus.kurttest.com/notes/tree23.html